# 2-way WebDAV sync app for macOS

Tags: macos, sync, webdav

I need to sync local folder with remote WebDAV server in both directions. Like Dropbox, but for WebDAV. I know about [DAVBox](http://www.pincette.biz/davbox/index.xhtml). Thought it mostly works, it's written in Java, requires more RAM than similar apps and not too power efficient.

Are there any alternatives for 2-way WebDAV sync?

FYI, DAVBox is actually not bad, but native solution (or least without Java) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the WebDAV share is mounted and editable in the Finder, you could use [unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync on OS X, Windows and Linux. It's available via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Thanks, but very slow. Scans files almost 12 hours before every sync and then during sync skips a lot of files with `The source file $file has been modified but the fast update detection mechanism failed to detect it.  Try running once with the fastcheck
option set to 'no'.`

Comment: Actual reason — WebDAV doesn't support 'mtime' attribute transfer that forces unison to be used with `fastcheck=no`, which is obviously ineffective with large data structures.